# tensorflow.compat in Google Colab not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm in Google Colab and I am trying to import tensorflow.compat but it says that it's missing the import.

I used `!pip install tensorflow==2.11.0` and tried to install lower versions too. But Colab still can't find tensorflow.compat. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @jricks72, I was able to import `tensorflow.compat` successfully in Google Colab, please find the gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/7c812830f97178542de1a5cafbf009c9/untitled221.ipynb). Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering my question. The official Tensorflow documentation states that they deprecated tf.compat and instead recommends tf.keras.

Comment: all the APIs under `tf.compat.v1` are deprecated.  `tf.compat` also contains a set of helper functions for writing code that works in both TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x. Thank you!